# How can I deploy UI updates on the fly locally in my dev environment?

Tags: joomla-3.x, templates

I am new to Joomla.  I want to setup a development environment through Visual Studio Code that allows me to go into any Joomla template location to edit/save/compile files AND automatically reload my browser to reflect my changes.

I want this process to occur for...

- SASS to CSS changes,
- Template PHP/HTML code changes
- Javascript changes.

Is this possible?  Is there a guide for me to follow to get this rocking?

My desire is to spend an extensive amount of time in theming.  Having a system setup in this way will allow me to work more efficiently.

Comment: Personally, I would do this with NodeJS and a task manager such as Gulp. I created a small script a while back (doesn't use gulp or grunt) that detects file changes in a directory and executes a shell script. You can change the code and replace the shell script execution snippet with something that compiles you LESS/SCSS files.

Comment: @Lodder many thanks!  I am also seeing that Gulp and npm would be a good way to go about this process.  Thanks for sharing your vision.